# Batch Processing in Azure Data Factory Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm new to ADF pipelines. I want to read files from on-prem loc and copy to the ADLS in batches of specific size(2 GB). For example, if there are 200 files, it will read all the files and sequentially pass the group of files (< 2GB) to the next process/pipeline. So, how to add the sizes of the files in ADF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the file size with multiple calls to the Get Metadata activity and there is a nice example [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/a83712ef-9a1a-4741-80b5-0e2ee8288ef5/get-child-items-size?forum=AzureDataFactory) of how to do that.  The `Get Metadata` activity does not return file size when using the `Child Items` field.  You can get `Size` if you specify an individual file.  Some other potential methods for on-premises or cloud data sources, eg Custom Activity - eg run some batch commands, Web activity - eg call the storage api, Notebook - eg run some python.

One alternate way would be to use the `Max rows per file` option of the Copy activity:

[image]

For a given table you could specify the max number of rows per file and that would approximate to 2GB file size, so a different approach but the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an If Condition activity (Search in the Activities for If Condition).
Then you need to Get the Metadata of the file that you want to check. In Metadata, you'll get the size of the file.

[Reference Link to Get Metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65169513/4483395)

Once you get the Metadata you can add Batch Processing Activity depending on your file size condition.

Comment: That's for single files. I need to add the file in batches and once it reaches 2 GB, then I need to copy the entire batch at once.

Comment: Where exactly are you adding the files? Are you copying them to any storage account?

Comment: Yes, I'm copying files them to ADLS V2 location.

Comment: What is the source of the files?

Comment: It's on on-prem loc, that is also on ADLS V2.