# How to check if files present under a data lake directory are empty using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, filesize, azure-data-factory

How to check if files present under a data lake directory are empty using Azure Data Factory?

There are multiple files present in the data lake directory and I want to check if these files are empty or not, If files are empty then I want to store the filenames of these empty files in a CSV File.

Comment: Are all these files present in the same directory?

Comment: Yes same folder contains both Empty Files and Non Empty Files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed this thread [Azure Data Factory V2 Check file size for Copy Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65152580/azure-data-factory-v2-check-file-size-for-copy-activity) and applied if condition to judge the file size and append variable and set variable to store the file names, Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether the file is empty or not Please follow the below Steps. I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and I got the below results:

In my storage account, I have two files one is `demo123.csv` empty and another one is a `vm_name3.csv` non-empty file.

[image]

**Please follow these Steps:**

**Step1:** First Create Get metadata with child items

[image]

**Step 2:** Add dynamic expression `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems` on the **forEach activity**.

[image]

- Create a dataset parameter
  [image]

**Step3 :** Inside **forEach activity** ->use lookup and If condition. Add this dynamic expression on **lookup activity** : `@item().name`

> **Lookup**

[image]

> **If condition:**

Using this dynamic expression `@equals(activity('Lookup1').output. count,0)`.You will know whether a file is empty or not.

[image]

- Then add append variable inside True conduction.
  [image]
- I created two variables with array type.

[image]

- Add this dynamic expression: `@item().name` on append variable
  [image]

**Step4:**

Add set variable to the forEach activity:
[image]

After successful execution of pipeline. I got empty file name:

[image]

If you want to store the filenames of these empty files in a CSV File .Then follow this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74471581/how-to-copy-the-data-from-append-variable-activity-to-a-csv-file-using-azure-dat/74475906#74475906) thread by Aswin

Comment: What should be the dataset of Lookup activity ?

Comment: Hi @Anonymous, delimitedtext2

Comment: It should point to ?

Comment: I'm getting this error while trying to debug                                                                     
"var1
Variable value should be a valid array; e.g. ["1","2","3"]"

Comment: Can you please provide that error message

Comment: Pipeline validation output
var1
Variable value should be a valid array; e.g. ["1","2","3"]

Comment: Yes, it is valid array. Just check once with `Val1` variable. your providing string or array.

Comment: I have provided Array type only..

Comment: What should be the data set path of Look Up Activity ?

Comment: Can u pls share the dataset connection image of both Getmeta data and Look Up Datasets ?

Comment: hi @Anonymous, please check above approach and step by step process.you will find above dataset connection image of both Getmeta data and Look Up Datasets and also data set path of Look Up Activity.

Comment: I think something is wrong with my Look Up Dataset

Comment: I assume Lookup Dataset should point to the same directory as Getmeta data Dataset ?

Comment: Go to step1 check once I take different dataset as you can see delimitedtext1 and step3 lookup I taken delimitedtext2. only one reason metadata it uses dataset as Json. so, I create separate dataset for look up and taken as array.

Comment: In your case delimitedtext1 data set is pointing to the folder where those 2 files are present and what delimitedtext2 data set is pointing to  ? Is it a dummy file ?